# get value from second pair of brackets, ignore data from first pair

Tags: jquery, regex, extract

I'm looking for a way to get the value from a second pair of brackets.

this is an example :
var foo = "bar - (cocktails) - (drunk);

Now I need the value "drunk", but not the value "cocktails".

I managed to get the value from the first pair, but still struggling to get the data from the second pair.

This is my code to extract the first value :

```
 var foo = "bar - (cocktails) - (drunk)";
 chosenfoo = foo;
 filterOut  = /\((.*)\)/i;
 var strippedFoo=  chosenfoo.match(filterOut)[1];
 $('#foobarfield').val(strippedFoo);
```

I was too brave to think that changing the number 1 to 2 would solve it. :)

When the value would be "bar - (cocktails)" then I'll get it right, like "cocktails", but with the previously given var with both pairs of brackets the result value for this code is :

> cocktails) - (drunk

not exactly what I want :(

anyone can help me on this one?

Comment: Second or the last pair of parentheses?

Comment: In this case the second pair. Allthough, aiming for the last one would also do the trick for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at below example

```js
var foo = "bar - (cocktails) - (drunk)";
var strippedFoo=  foo.match(/\((.*?)\)/gi)[1].replace(/\(|\)/g, "");;
alert(strippedFoo)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: oh damn.. yeah.. well.. I thought it could have been done inside the regex, but after seeing this the solution was just in front of me :p
Tnx a million for this very clear answer & solution

Comment: @George Glad that I'm able to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want with two changes:

- add `/g` for global matches (multiple matches) otherwise it stops on first match
- add `?` to mean (basically) 'shortest match possible'

As in:

```
/\((.*?)\)/gi
```

With the change to /g, the return is an array of matches, so first is `[0]` and second `[1]`

Snippet:

```js
var foo = "bar - (cocktails) - (drunk)";
chosenfoo = foo;
filterOut  = /\((.*?)\)/gi;
var strippedFoo=  chosenfoo.match(filterOut)[1];
$('#foobarfield').text(strippedFoo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='foobarfield'></div>
```

Comment: ok, this is pretty close to the result I want to get, but for some reason it is adding the brackets to the result.. So now I have (cocktails) and (drunk) as seperated values, so how can I adapt this to get "cocktails" and "drunk" without the brackets?
don't get me wrong, when I'm aiming for just the first with the original code, I do get "cocktails"... so what's making the difference here?

Comment: I would probably just go with a `.replace` but seemed that wasn't what you wanted, so I was looking into non-capturing groups and look-ahead for you.   It's not clear why JS is including the brackets as I feel (eg) C# wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

you are matching everything between the 1st and the very last parenthesis.
fix your regex like this

```
/\((.*?)\)/gi
```

and you should end up with 2 captures

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last bracket with this:

```
\((?!.*\().*\)
```

And with this one you can get the last complete bracket even if there is a non-complete bracket (just one `(` or `)`) at the end:

```
\((?!.*\(.*\)).*?\)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/LMGtvj/1)

**Update** to match the content of brackets:

```
\((?!.*\(.*\))(.*?)\)
```

Comment: This code also returns the value with the brackets like "(cocktails)" and "(drunk)"... I need these without the brackets itself.

Comment: Your code exactly with the updated answer will give expected result.